# auto-test and mock opensmpp message exchange

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, opensmpp

I wrote a code that communicates with provider by SMPP protocol, using [OpenSMPP](http://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp). Now I want to add some autotests for that: start my own smpp server running on localhost:port, send message there from my code, mock response, check that sent parameters are ok, etc as with any web mocks. Looked through OpenSMPP sources but can't find any example. They have simulation tool in subproject, but I would like to avoid starting external processes. Any solution available?